# $X$ and $Y$ are two random variable representing a roll of a dice. What is the probability distribution of $X+Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ and $Y$ are two random variables representing a roll of a dice. What is the probability distribution of $X+Y$?

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variable $X + Y$ takes values in $\{2, 3, ..., 12\}$. For each possible value of $X+Y$ you just have to count the number of outcomes with that value. For example: What is the probability that $X+Y = 9$? The pairs $(X,Y)$ that achieve this sum are
\begin{equation}
(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 4) \text{ and } (6, 3).
\end{equation}
Dividing by the total number of possibilities we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X + Y = 9) = \frac{4}{36} = \frac 19.
\end{equation}